# Fancybox slider resets to 1st slide when selecting slide in middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a Fancybox slider that has thumbnails that become 'active' on the bigger viewport on click. Then -- if you click the bigger viewport, it opens the modal slider. The only issue is when the modal pops up with the slide you choose, clicking 'next' takes you back to the first slide, and *then* proceeds through the rest of the slides. Vanilla Fancybox 2.1.5

I'd post the code, but it's vanilla Fancybox, and it's nearly 1500 lines long. I'm assuming it has to do with the current.index + 1 positioning inside the 'next' function.

Basically, I want to tell Fancybox what the index of the current slide is when it goes to modal, so when they click 'next', it *actually* goes to the next slide. (i.e. Clicks on slide index 39, 'next' goes to 40, and so on...). Right now, it goes [clicks on] index 39 --> 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({ 
            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Another script that may be of importance(?):

```
<script>
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to post your custom code (where you initialize fancybox) and not the plugin source code

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: I would love to see the javascript code you use to initialize fancybox, something like `$(".fancybox").fancybox({ ... })`

Comment: I didn't realize I couldn't block out code in a comment, so I will amend the original post to include the code you're looking for, though I don't think it's going to help much. Thanks!